# passing android:fontFamily to custom view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

How do you pass a font family inside the `res/font` folder, e.g. `@font/roboto_medium`, as an attribute to a custom view in Android in XML, and then read it inside the custom view into a `Typeface` object?  This is necessary to do custom graphical rendering of the text.

For example:

```
<MyCustomView android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"/>
```

Then inside MyCustomView.kt:

```
override fun onCreateView(...) {

  // parse android:fontFamily attribute into Typeface object
  val typeface: Typeface = ???  

}
```

None of the `Typeface` functions seems to support this.  One  of them accepts a custom font inside the `assets` folder, and another accepts a resource font integer directly embedded inside the Java/Kotlin code e.g. `R.font.roboto_medium`.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to add some detail here about what you have tried already and where you're getting stuck. There are lots of tutorials on the web on how to create and use custom XML attributes in your custom views. You will often find that you get better, more helpful responses here if you show the effort that you've put into working out the solution, and exactly how you've gotten stuck.

Comment: I looked everywhere including other Stack Overflow threads but could not find a Typeface function that would accept font family XML attribute.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer of doohickey_maker really works.

In layout.xml you need to add `android:fontFamily="@font/name"`

In attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="LoadingButton">
<attr name="android:fontFamily" />
```

In CustomView

```
   int fontFamilyId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_fontFamily, 0);
   if (fontFamilyId > 0) {
       mButton.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), fontFamilyId));
   }
```

Comment: If you want it complete custom you can do it like this:

    <declare-styleable name="LoadingButton">
    <attr name="loadingFont" format="string"/>

Comment: In CustomView
    val fontFamilyId: Int = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.LoadingButton_loadingFont, 0)
        if (fontFamilyId > 0) {
            mButton.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), fontFamilyId))
        }

Answer (score 1):

Use `TypedArray.getResourceId` to convert the font family attribute to an ID, and then use `ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, fontId)` to get the `Typeface`.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.
if you want to create a custom view and then pass the font, check this link:

https://medium.com/@nikk.dave/android-apply-custom-font-from-xml-e7ed5fada019

if you want to just set custom font in XML file, check this link to learn:
https://www.spritle.com/blogs/2017/11/03/set-custom-font-xml-file/

about your second question, I don't know why you need typeface, but it's easy for android views:
textview.getTypeface();

Comment: Neither of those links answers how to pass @font (a font inside res folder) to a custom view and then read it from the custom view.  The first link you posted reads fonts from asset folder, and the second link does not involve a custom view.

Comment: Unfortunately, the direct answer to your question is that it cannot be done in the way that you want. This answer provides pointers to a couple of different alternatives that are available.